# Issue with /@ and @ functions

Tags: list-manipulation

I have the following list of points (ccmppp1) as an output from part of my scripts which is a list of lists. To find the Mean of each sublist, I am using the following script which works well.

`trcentrpp = Mean /@ ccmppp1`

However, When my output is a list (e.g ccmppp2) the above script gives the wrong output and I should use the following script.

`trcentrpp = Mean @ ccmppp2`

Considering that I do not know if my output is a list or list of list which command should I use that works for both. Or should I use the If function which I prefer not to use?

ccmppp1 = {{{45.8144, -0.864685, 10.7009}, {42.6579, -0.863343,
10.01}, {44.2365, -0.830501, 10.3459}, {171.179,
305.888, -107.992}}, {{173.75, 306.062, -108.301}, {171.775,
307.219, -110.29}, {174.06, 307.508, -111.119}, {170.034,
307.95, -111.296}, {174.329, 309.043, -113.554}, {172.091,
309.352, -113.408}, {169.571, 309.361, -113.06}, {169.98,
311.135, -115.16}, {174.687, 311.218, -116.291}, {172.25,
311.487, -115.947}, {173.124, 312.642, -117.252}, {174.887,
312.839, -117.922}}, {{168.792, 313.106, -116.923}, {171.072,
313.217, -117.375}, {173.008, 314.374, -118.78}, {175.094,
314.559, -119.475}, {169.427, 314.727, -118.452}, {171.107,
314.919, -118.858}, {173.699, 315.855, -120.169}, {170.027,
316.188, -119.749}, {175.261, 316.204, -120.815}, {171.812,
316.454, -120.228}, {173.568, 317.473, -121.382}, {169.795,
317.828, -121.02}, {175.483, 318.03, -122.247}, {171.704,
318.423, -121.752}}}

ccmppp2 = {{171.812, 316.454, -120.228}, {173.568,
317.473, -121.382}, {169.795, 317.828, -121.02}, {175.483,
318.03, -122.247}, {171.704, 318.423, -121.752}, {173.455,
319.502, -122.871}, {175.579, 319.568, -123.379}, {171.569,
320.011, -122.921}, {172.051, 321.326, -123.958}, {173.959,
321.362, -124.319}, {175.775, 321.389, -124.718}, {172.506,
323.092, -125.281}, {174.385, 323.193, -125.675}, {176.134,
323.528, -126.258}, {174.903, 324.765, -126.81}, {173.108,
325.129, -126.751}, {176.3, 325.268, -127.376}, {174.762,
326.297, -127.72}, {176.462, 327.022, -128.426}, {176.555,
328.653, -129.344}, {178.005, 342.933, -137.562}, {178.125,
344.653, -138.456}, {178.235, 346.388, -139.252}, {75.5718,
436.359, -80.7434}, {76.131, 438.132, -87.7129}, {76.9078,
439.652, -94.7067}}

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try `Map[Mean, #, {-3}]`

```
Map[Mean, ccmppp1, {-3}]
```

> ```
> {{75.9719, 75.8324, -19.2338}, {172.545, 309.651, -113.633}, 
>  {172.132,315.811, -119.802}}
> ```

```
Map[Mean, ccmppp2, {-3}]
```

> ```
> {163.186, 337.94, -121.956}
> ```

This would also work if you have even deeper nesting.

**EDIT**

Regarding the question in the comments, you could use

```
Map[Mean, {#}, {-3}] /. {{a__List}} :> {a} &
```

to ensure that the result is always a list of lists (which would again work for deeper nestings).

```
Map[Mean, {#}, {-3}] /. {{a__List}} :> {a} & @ ccmppp1
```

> ```
> {{75.9719, 75.8324, -19.2338}, {172.545, 309.651, -113.633}, 
>  {172.132,315.811, -119.802}}
> ```

```
Map[Mean, {#}, {-3}] /. {{a__List}} :> {a} & @ ccmppp2
```

> ```
> {{163.186, 337.94, -121.956}}
> ```

Comment: Thank you very much! It worked. Also, I need to plot the point using the List Point Plot 3D command is there any way that I have the output in double braces (i.e {{163.186, 337.94, -121.956}}) so that I can plot it as well. It should be noticed that the first one does not need extra braces to plot.

Comment: @MehdiEbadi - you don't need extra brackets if you use `Show`, i.e.,  `Show[ListPointPlot3D[ccmppp1, PlotRange -> All, PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.25]], Graphics3D[{Red, AbsolutePointSize[6], Point[trcentrpp1]}]]` (note that `Opacity` is needed since two of the means are buried in a cluster) and `Show[ListPointPlot3D[ccmppp2, PlotRange -> All], Graphics3D[{Red, AbsolutePointSize[6], Point[trcentrpp2]}]]`. `Point` can accept either a coordinate or a list of coordinates.

Comment: Than you again Hausdorff and Bob. I have a quick question! How do you know that you should use level {-3} in Map?

Comment: You can see the depths of objects in an expression using ```TreeForm```. ```{-3}``` just means that the function will be mapped to everything at the third lowest level. To see how that works in practice you can play around with the level ```i``` in ```Map[f, ccmppp1, {-i}]``` and see what ```f``` gets applied to.